# Form, AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a simple Subscribe form that I want to get the contents of an 'email' input to post to a MySQL db using AJAX. This is successfully creating a record with the date and time but not inserting the email address.

Can anyone see what's wrong with the following please?

form.php

```
<form id="subscribe" action="?action=signup" method="post" data-abide>
  <div class="row collapse">
    <div class="large-10 large-centered columns">
      <div class="row collapse postfix-radius">
        <div class="small-9 columns">
    <div class="email-field">
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" required>
      <small style="padding-left:10px; "class="error">Please enter a valid email address</small>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="small-3 columns">

      <input type="submit" id="button" class="button success postfix" value="Subscribe">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<span style="display:none;" id="message"><small><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> Subscribed</small></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#subscribe').submit(function(){

        var data = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'subscribe_insert.php',
            data: data,
                success: function(data) {
            $("#message").fadeIn(250);
                }
            });
        return false;
   });
});
</script>
```

subscribe_insert.php

```
<?php

   include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/dbconnect.php");

   $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
   $date_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

   $sql  = "INSERT INTO subscribe 
            (email,
            date)
            VALUES
            ('$email',
            '$date_time')"; 

   if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

?>
```

Thanks,

John

Comment: Have you checked  var_dump($_POST) in php file ?

Comment: Like said, post a var_dump of the post data

Comment: don't use deprecated version of `mysql_*` .Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with `prepared statements`.Easy to use, prevent all security loop-holes

Comment: where do I place the var_dump($_POST) command? I won't see the results if it's in the ajax called php file.

Comment: You can place it right in the file where you insert the data, To see the var_dump results, send the form as it is now (using ajax) but be sure to have the console opened before sending it. In chrome you have to also have the keep "Log XMLHttpRequests" checkbox checked, then when you see the request that your ajax call made click the php file and go to response, there you'll see the var_dump results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#subscribe').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serialize();
console.log(data)
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                 dataType: 'JSON',
                url: 'subscribe_insert.php',
            data: data,
                success: function(data) {
            $("#message").fadeIn(250);
                }
            });
        return false;
   });
});
```

replace your code with this  then open your browser console and check if the data s getting posted

if you can see the your email there then check if the data is at the server

in you php page copy all the contents from the page  and replace

```
<?php 
 echo json_encode($_POST)
?>
```

and once again check console this time you should see data from the server

if both are correct put your original php code back it

Comment: I did as you said and I could see the email address fine. Unfortunately, still not inserting the email address into the db. I am now guessing its something with the following line: $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

Comment: in your db is your email data type set to string?

Comment: It's set to a varchar

Comment: hmm if its still not working replace  `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])` with a string `abc` see if that adds to db

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp refer to this site for prepared statments

Comment: Replaced it with abc and it did insert abc into the db

Comment: please use prepare statements they make life easier also its helps with preventing sql inection

Comment: i attached a ink above

Answer (score 0):

Check in your database that email has the correct attributes:

For exaple check that you have at least x characters allowed to be stored, check for the type of the field:

It could be `int` when it it really should be something like `varchar`

**`var_dump` details:**

form.php is ok for this purpose.
But we are going to modify the php file temporarily to check for "post" error in the email field:

```
<?php

   include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/dbconnect.php");

   $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
   var_dump($email);  //dump email value
   /* comment this peace
   $date_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

   $sql  = "INSERT INTO subscribe 
            (email,
            date)
            VALUES
            ('$email',
            '$date_time')"; 

   if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      echo "";
   } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
   }
  */

?>
```

**Now follow the next steps:**

1. Open chrome
2. Open your webpage
3. Hit F12
4. Check the "Log XMLHttpRequests" checkbox
5. Send your form and you will se something in the console like: XHR finished loading: POST http://localhost//folder/subscribe_insert.php
6. Click the logged url of your console
7. You may see a list of resources (depends of your project)
8. Click the one that has the subscribe_insert.php title
9. To your right you will see some tabs click response

If there was some error or some data was echoed from that file (In this case our var_dump) you will see it there.

If you see the email actually printing out It might be a database problem as I started tellong you.

I know there are too many steps but it's very fast to do it, I hope I have helped you, greeting!